# get LoginName string value

Tags: vb.net

I am using VB.NET and trying to get the value in the control LoginName1. I need this in string value for a parameter. I am not sure how to get this. I have tried the following which returns "system.web.UI.WebControls.LoginName". `Dim txt As LoginName = DirectCast(LoginName1.FindControl("LoginName1"), LoginName)`

```
<div style="float: left">
    Welcome
<asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" />
    <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Comment: They should be properties on your code behind class unless it's in a repeater or similiar control. `dim txt as LoginName = LoginName1`

Comment: Think you might be nearly there, just need to check the .Text property of LoginName1 when doing the FindControl

Comment: Hursey, I am not sure how you mean I should do this

Comment: @Martha If you look at the documentation for the [LoginName Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginname), it says "By default, the LoginName control displays the name contained in the User property of the Page class." with links which you can follow to see how to get the information it looks like you're after.

Comment: Hi Hursey, Sorry I am only getting back to this now. I am still struggling to achieve what I am trying to. do you perhaps have an example of some sample code ?